# Code seems to execute fine in Node.Js but e-mail is still not sent

Tags: node.js, email, html-email

```
'use strict'
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'yyyy@outlook.com',
    pass: 'zzzzz'
  }
})

let mailOptions = {
  from: 'yyyy@outlook.com',
  to: 'xxxxx@in.ibm.com, xxxxx@gmail.com',
  subject: 'wah wah wah wah',
  text: 'ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho/n  lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo'
}
```

Note: E-mail address and passwords changed but in the original script, I use correct ones.
console.log('Message sent:')

Comment: you did not post complete code. Post complete code here

Comment: You don't send the email at all. Provide the whole code.

Comment: I got the answer now :)

I changed Secure: True to Secure: False

This has fixed the situation

Answer (score 1):

```
'use strict'
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'yyyy@outlook.com',
    pass: 'zzzzz'
  }
})

let mailOptions = {
  from: 'yyyy@outlook.com',
  to: 'xxxxx@in.ibm.com, xxxxx@gmail.com',
  subject: 'wah wah wah wah',
  text: 'ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho/n  lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo lo'
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response)
  }
})
```

I guess you have missed the last portion. Please try this.

Comment: You are right sir .... I forgot to add last part and got solution too :)

Answer: Changed Secure: true to Secure: False and working now

Comment: The answer is simple: I made an error,,, changing secure: true to Secure false did the trick... now getting e-mails